# Foreach callback when finish

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to execute a callback when `foreach` has finished, but it's not working properly.How can I do that?

```
var response = [];
myArray.forEach(function(data) {
    data.asyncFunction(function(result) {
         response.push(result);
    });
}, function() {
    console.log(response); // Not being called.
});

console.log(response); // (Empty) Executed before foreach finish.
```

Comment: Are you doing any asynchronous action within the `forEach`?

Comment: *"// (Empty) Executed before foreach finish."* Incorrect assumption. The forEach is in fact complete. you are misdiagnosing the problem. Please provide more context to your question.

Comment: @thefourtheye I edited because I'm using an asynchronous function inside my foreach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `forEach` accept only one `callback`. Since you are calling asynchronous method inside `forEach` you need to check whether all asyn call completed

```
var response = [];
myArray.forEach(function(data, index) {
    data.asyncFunction(function(result) {
         response.push(result);
         if(response.length  === myArray.length) {
                 //foreach work done
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: I edited my question because I'm using an asynchronous function inside the foreach. Could you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: if it is truly asynchronous, you can't trust that when the last index is called they are all done. better to compare myArray.length to response.length.

Comment: @Anoop Thank you guys, I got it! And sorry about the stupid question.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento it is not stupid question. it happen with every one

Comment: You can use a simple integer variable and compare with **myArray.length** too (example: `if( itemsProcessed === myArray.length )` )

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
myArray.forEach(function(element, index, array){
  asynchronous(function(data){
       if (index === myArray.length - 1) {
           response.push(data);
           functionAfterForEach();
       }
  })
});
```

Comment: `myArray` is not changing... so whenever you call for it's length it will give the correct length @Kevin B

Comment: the comment was of course to the original iteration of your answer. though, i think it still stands. if the last iteration of the loop finishes anything other than last, you'll call the callback too soon.

Comment: sorry @Kevin B it was a silly mistake for me

Comment: sorry, see edits to comment. i have a bad habit of hitting enter in comments before i'm done. :)